# How to install Google input tools in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: software-installation

How can I install Google input tools in Ubuntu 17.04?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot install it for general use on Ubuntu, as it is only available as a general download for Windows.

If you use Chrome or Chromium for your browser, however, you can install the extension from the Chrome extensions store, to use within the browser.

There are links to install it from https://www.google.com/inputtools/try/